# Touch settings for Xcode writing in HTML as I have phonegap involved

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, drag-and-drop, xcode5

I'm trying to allow an image to be swiped away in four directions (UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT). My code is correct, however I'm unable to even press down and move an image, so I can't even incorporate a simple drag and drop feature which works perfectly in the browser. I'm wondering if I need to enable something or do something with a config file?

Clicking works fine, but I can't drag or interact with any elements in the simulator. I'm making reference to the CSS like below. So I believe everything to be correct in the code. Seems to be a settings issue to allow my java script drag and down functions to work.

```
 #drag1 { -webkit-user-drag: element; }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script worked great.

```
<script>


var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('contents');

for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++) {
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
                         var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

                         // Place element where the finger is
                         event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
                         event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
                         event.preventDefault();


         });


}



</script>
```